# Trying to get a value from a html code by using beautiful soap but have hard time to get it

Tags: python

Trying to find the value shown in the picture below [image] from the website https://www.coop.se/butiker-erbjudanden/coop/coop-ladugardsangen-/ with help of beautiful soap code. But the only value I get is the price number and not the "st" value.

Here is the code I try to use to get it...

CODE

```
test = product.find('span', class_='Splash-content ')
    print(Price.text)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bsoup
site_source = requests.get("https://www.coop.se/butiker-erbjudanden/coop/coop-ladugardsangen-/").content
soup = bsoup(site_source, "html.parser")
all_items = soup.find("div", class_="Section Section--margin")
item_list = soup.find_all("span", class_="Splash-content")
for item in item_list:
    print("Price: ",item.find("span", class_="Splash-priceLarge").text)
    if item.find("span", class_="Splash-priceSub Splash-priceUnitNoDecimal"):
        print("Unit: ",item.find("span", class_="Splash-priceSub Splash-priceUnitNoDecimal").text)
```

In some cases the unit is missing so we want to make sure we handle for that.

My understanding is that you basically want to print the price and unit of each item so that is what i attempt to do.

Comment: Good answer but don't "expand" it on your own. Let the OP ask.

Answer (score 0):

try with :

```
url = "https://www.coop.se/butiker-erbjudanden/coop/coop-ladugardsangen-/"
try:
    page = urllib.request.urlopen(url, timeout=20)
except HTTPError as e:
    page = e.read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(page, 'html.parser')
body = soup.find('body')
result = body.find("span", class_="Splash-content")
print(result.get_text())
```

for me it worked !